# Sum up column between two dates, group by 3 columns - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sum, group

Can someone please suggest a way to sum up the "count" column between two dates and group it according to the **"mcc"**, **"partner"** and **"result"** columns.

***"Stats"** table:*

| id | date | count | mcc | partner | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-13 | 4 | 293 | TynTec | SUCCESS |
| 2 | 2022-07-13 | 5 | 293 | TynTec | FATAL |
| 3 | 2022-07-13 | 4 | 294 | NTH | SUCCESS |
| 4 | 2022-07-14 | 9 | 294 | NTH | SUCCESS |
| 5 | 2022-07-14 | 4 | 294 | TynTec | SUCCESS |
| 6 | 2022-07-14 | 10 | 294 | NTH | FATAL |

Desired output:

| id | date | count | mcc | partner | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-13 - 2022-07-14 | 8 | 293 | TynTec | SUCCESS |
| 2 | 2022-07-13 - 2022-07-14 | 5 | 293 | TynTec | FATAL |
| 3 | 2022-07-13 - 2022-07-14 | 13 | 294 | NTH | SUCCESS |
| 4 | 2022-07-13 - 2022-07-14 | 10 | 294 | NTH | FATAL |

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you.

```
   select concat(mindv , ' - ' , maxdv) as dates, 
          sum(cnt) as counts,
          min(mcc) as mcc,
          partner,
          res as result 
   from tmp_1,
   (select min(dt) as mindv ,partner as pmin from tmp_1 group by 2) mind,
   (select max(dt) as maxdv , partner as pmax  from tmp_1 group by 2) maxd
   where 
      mind.pmin=maxd.pmax
      and partner=mind.pmin
      group by 1,4,5;
```

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code returns the result that you want; It didn't optimize but gives you the idea of what you have to do:

```
SELECT  
    CONVERT(char(10), T.[date],126) +
    ' - '
    + CONVERT(char(10), DATEADD(DAY,IIF(DATEDIFF(DAY, T.[date], NextDate) 
IS NOT NULL, DATEDIFF(DAY, T.[date], NextDate),1),T.[date]),126),
    T.ItemCount
    T.mcc,
    T.[partner],
    T.[result]
FROM    (SELECT T1.*,(SELECT  MIN([date]) FROM (SELECT 
            SUM([count]) AS ItemCount,
            [mcc], 
            [partner], 
            [result],
            DATEADD(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, [date])) AS [date]
        FROM [TABLENAME] 
        WHERE [date] between '[FromDate]' and '[ToDate]'
        GROUP BY [mcc], [partner], [result], dateadd(DAY,0, DATEDIFF(DAY,0, 
  [date]))) AS T2
                    WHERE   T2.mcc = T1.mcc AND T2.[partner]=T1.[partner] 
AND T2.[result]=T1.[result]
                    AND     T2.[date] > T1.[date]
                ) AS NextDate
FROM (SELECT 
            SUM([count]) AS ItemCount,
            [mcc], 
            [partner], 
            [result],
            DATEADD(DAY,0, DATEDIFF(day,0, [date])) AS [date]
        FROM [TABLENAME] 
        WHERE [date] between '[FromDate]' and '[ToDate]'
        GROUP BY [mcc], [partner], [result] , DATEADD(DAY,0, 
DATEDIFF(DAY,0, [date]))) AS T1 )AS T
```

To describe a quick and short senario about the code :

1. I generate a query that `GROUP BY` columns you said and the date.
2. Then I get `NextDate` of **SELECT** Statement to generate **Time Period**
3. In final step I select the columns that you want from table and generate **Time Period** related to `Date` and `NextDate`

---

note: If `NextDate` column be null generated date automatically add one day to  **Time Period**.

If you have any questions write them below in the comments.

Comment: Sorry, my SQL knowledge isnt great, where would I input the 2 dates in the given code? And I take it that I can substitute [TABLENAME] for "Stats"? Thank you so much!

Comment: Exactly you can substitute [TABLENAME] for "Stats". Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out what you mean by the first question. Do you mean you want to set a condition to select data in the assumed period?

Comment: Yes, if for instance, I wanted the date range to be 01/01/2022 - 31/06/2022. Thank you

Comment: @Webbo I update my answer. Now You can see two `WHERE` statements in the query and replace [FromDate] and [ToDate] with your range. For example: `WHERE [date] between '2022-01-01' and '2022-06-31'`